# Dialing Contribution Aggregate by Relationship back a few year

Tags: reports, date-preferences

TL;DR: I want Contribution Aggregate by Relationship to show more years in the past.

I'm using the report "Contribution Aggregate by Relationship" to produce a report with columns for giving by year. However, it doesn't go back as many years as I'd like. I found how to control how many years it goes *forward* ("custom" date class in Settings - Date Preferences), but the same date class doesn't affect how far it goes back (three previous years then a catch-all for years before that). Is there something else that controls this? I need it to go back about 10 years or so.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

My fix was to edit a file in "all", which isn't ideal since it'll get overwritten when updating CiviCRM, but I can always re-apply it.

Edit file: `sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Report/Form/Contribute/History.php`

Change Line 61 from `$yearsInPast = 4;` to `$yearsInPast = 20;`

Comment: What I usually do when I need to change a core report a bit. Is to create an extension into which copy&paste the code of the core report and change it to my needs. 
Also I would have changed the hardcoded variable into a filter option which could be set in the user interface.

Comment: As Jaap says, create an extension with a copy of the existing report then modify.  The `--copy` option on `civix generate:report` makes it very easy to get started.